# In a linked list, can comparing last node with next element cause Segmentation fault?

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am writing the code to remove duplicate elements from a sorted linked list in which I am comparing each element to the next element.

Here's the code:

```
void removeDuplicates(struct node* head)
{
    struct node* nextnext;
    struct node* current=head;

    if(current == NULL) 
        return;

    while(current != NULL) //Give Segmentation Fault
    {
        if(current->data == current->next->data)
        {
            nextnext = current->next->next;
            free(current->next);
            current->next=nextnext;
        }
        else
        {
            current = current->next;
        }

    }
}
```

If I simply change that while loop from `while(current != NULL)` to `while(current->next != NULL)`, the segmentation fault disappears.

When I printed the list after every line, its printing everything till the end before a segfault occurs. Does that mean comparing last node with the next element causes a segfault?

Comment: Well, it probably does. Reading through a null pointer typically causes segmentation fault. Why does such question even arise? Accessing data through null pointer is illegal anyway, regardless of whether it causes segmentation fault or not.

Comment: I believed null pointer contains null data. I am a beginner.

Comment: your testing shows that one element in the list has a next pointer that is junk - since we cant see how you made the list we cant help you

Comment: StackExchange should have a StackSchool - then "questions" from students homework could be redirected there.

Comment: Segmentation faults in linked lis code nearly always happen because you dereference an indeterminate or NULL pointer while doing *something*. That coupled with a debugger should make short work of finding the problem in your algorithm. And note: you should probably also mention in your question your algorithm is intending on removing **consecutive** duplicates (such as a sorted linked list) if that is the case; otherwise it is more wrong than you think.

Comment: @WhozCraig  yeah its for removing sorted linked list..

Comment: @user3387006 as I said, that really belongs in your question text. And if that is the case you may be surprised how simply the algorithm becomes once you really gel on it awhile. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segmentation fault is most likely caused by accessing the `current->next` members (like `current->next->data` or `current->next->next`), since you are not checking whether the `current->next` is `null`. If it is, the access to it's data members is a memory violation.

Answer (score 0):

The error probably occurs when you compare the last element to its *next* element.

The element next to the last element is NULL, hence the `Segmentation fault`.

Answer (score -1):

all right, i made few changes to your code.
First, notice the typedef that replaces the 'struct node*'
second, don't forget that you're dealing with a linked list, make sure you 
connect the current with the next node after the current->next after the freeing.

```
typdef struct node* Node;  /*this replaces the typo of 'struct node*' for more professional writing*/
void removeDuplicates(Node head)
{
    /*struct node* nextnext;  <<no need for this.
    struct node* current=head;*/
    Node current=head;
    if(current == NULL) 
        return; 
    while(current->next != NULL) 
    {
        Node nextNode = current->next; //if you work with c99, harness this feature of declaring here
        if(current->data == nextNode->data)
        {
            Node temp = nextNode->next;
            free(nextNode);
            current->next = temp;
        }
        current = current->next
        /* else
        {
            current = current->next;
        } */
        //you dont need this else condition since you're advancing the 
        //node to the next one anyways.
    }
}
```

you didn't provide the struct itself, so i did provide you with the idea of how to approach this.

hope it helped!